# Android - canvas drawBitmap displaying top left quarter of image

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

When I call drawBitmap with the (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint) implementation, I only get the top left quarter of the image displayed - my source image is 16x16 but only 8x8 is displayed.

```
rSource = new Rect();
rDest = new Rect();
rSource.set(0,0,16,16);
rDest.set(0,0,16,16);
canvas.drawBitmap(tiles, rSource, rDest, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to sort this out myself. Read up on device independent pixels vs. physical pixels. As I'm using an XHDPI device, everything is x 2 of the baseline MDPI.